# POST PHP data to MYSQL server from Phone App

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I am looking to receive POST data from an Android app and put it into a MYSQL server using PHP to script.

I am getting no results and I have gone through various examples and tutorials.

NEW WORKING PHP SCRIPT

```
<?php
$needsarray = str_split('$_POST[needs]');
$needs1 = 0;
$needs2 = 0;
$needs3 = 0;
$needs4 = 0;

if ($needsarray[0] =="1"){
 $needs1 = 1;
}
if ($needsarray[1] =="1"){
 $needs2 = 1;
}
if ($needsarray[2] =="1"){
 $needs3 = 1;
}
if ($needsarray[3] =="1"){
 $needs4 = 1;
}

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","haitidis_test","S3an");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

 mysql_select_db("haitidis_AppData", $con);

$sql="INSERT INTO Extensive (disaster, people, lat, lng, phone, needs1, needs2, needs3,    needs4) 
VALUES ('$_POST[disaster]', '$_POST[people]', '$_POST[latitude]', '$_POST[longtitude]',     '$_POST[userphone]', $needs1, $needs2, $needs3, $needs4)";
if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "1 record added";
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: None of my code looks to have any errors.  I navigate to the page where the php script is hosted and nothing is there.  I am getting no errors in eclipse either.  I also am getting nothing inside my mysql db either.  I also created my own html form with the same data and tried to post it again to the php script and I still got nothing...I wish I had some errors at least it would give me something to work with

Comment: try printing response.getStatusLine();

Comment: Test From your form and try to echo something in the page of PHP

Comment: Im trying to get that going now, having a little trouble will post results asap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing really wrong with your code. I tested the Java code in my eclipse and the PHP looks fine. For starters try seeing if your phone code and php code actually talk to each other.

Add a `var_dump($_POST)` to the end PHP:

Change your code a little bit to this:

```
 ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
 String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);

 System.out.println(response);
```

Print the results. If your post values are printed, then then there's nothing wrong on the phone side. Maybe something is wrong in the PHP script although it's not obvious to me right now. If something went wrong with your connection, the

> 'Could not connect'

will be printed.

**UPDATE**: Since you said, nothing is being inserted into the database. Try doing this:

```
$result = mysql_query('PUT INSERT STATEMENT HERE');
var_dump($result);
```

If the result is false var dump the sql error:

```
var_dump(mysql_error());
```

**UPDATE:**

> Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Access denied for user 
>   'haitidis'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in
>   /home/haitidis/public_html/extensive.php on     line 42

Are you sure you are using the right password --- "S3an" ?

**UPDATE:**

You should put the following lines of code **before** closing your connection:

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO Extensive (disaster, people, lat, lng, phone, 
     needs1, needs2, needs3, needs4) VALUES ($disaster, $people, $lat, $long, $phone,     
    $needs1, $needs2, $needs3, $needs4)");

mysql_close($con);
```

Check your db now if the rows are being inserted.

Comment: I used the html test form I made and I clicked submit and I got the post values so that is a good sign I assume, however when I looked in my sql database it didnt show an added row!  I tried to get the ddms output but there was nothing listed so not sure whats going on there

Comment: Thanks for the help with Debugging that is a good idea with the mysql error.  I am going to keep trying I posted the error in my original post.  Thank you!

Comment: Yes I am actually what happened was I put the $result = mysql_query('PUT INSERT STATEMENT HERE'); after I closed the mysql connection.  I have moved it up and I am no longer receiving the error.  I have updated the output above in my question

Comment: Thanks so much for your help it is now working! I have posted the updated script in my answer above thank you again!